# Problems with _filelength and chsize

Tags: c

I have a file **exmpl.cpp**, which contains the next code (it`s from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dk925tyb.aspx)):

```
#include <sys/io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

void main( void )
{
   int fh, result;
   unsigned int nbytes = BUFSIZ;

   /* Open a file */
   if( (fh = open( "data", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IREAD
                   | S_IWRITE ))  != -1 )
   {
      printf( "File length before: %ld\n", filelength( fh ) );
      if( ( result = chsize( fh, 329678 ) ) == 0 )
         printf( "Size successfully changed\n" );
      else
         printf( "Problem in changing the size\n" );
      printf( "File length after:  %ld\n", _filelength( fh ) );
      close( fh );
   }
}
```

Try to compile it with `g++ exmpl.cpp -o exmpl`and get this:

> exmpl.cpp:18:60: error: ‘_filelength’ was not declared in this scope
> exmpl.cpp:19:43: error: ‘chsize’ was not declared in this scope

Are there any alternative functions, which are similar to these functions?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: _filelength is a Windows function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `_filelength` is a Windows-only function.

In Linux/Mac you can use `stat` for solving the task:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

long file_length(char *f)
{
    struct stat st;
    stat(f, &st);
    return st.st_size;
}
```

On changing file size. Function `chsize` is also not a Linux one, but you can use [`ftruncate`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate) to do the job.